# Tflite: Resize output tensor based on input tensor contents

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am writing a custom op that outputs a tensor whose shape depends on the values of the input tensor. The problem is that we don't have access to the tensor values in the `Prepare` method. We can get the tensor *shapes* but the *values* are not available. How do I implement this?

On a related note, how do I support outputting a tensor with partially specified shape? The tensor would need to be allocated during the `eval` function, but I don't see an API to allocate tensors at run time.

Comment: From what you describe you might want to use dynamic tensors in your custom op. One of the simpler examples is the [Pad op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/pad.cc). In this example, in the case of a dynamic input tensor, the output tensor shape is set in Eval instead of Prepare.

Comment: Pad op = https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/pad.cc



**Link is expired

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22377#issuecomment-444550814